# Parallel vs Distributed automation testing with selenium grid

Tags: selenium, ui-automation, selenium-grid

Automation testers always use words "**Parallel**" & "**Distributed**" testing interchangeably.

For me **Selenium Grid** helps to finish automation test run quickly by "**distributing**" test cases to available machines ( nodes ).

Currently I use docker based selenium grid + node mechanism for quicker execution of automated regression suite on single mac machine. 
This setup gets triggered by jenkins job whenever there is a new build tag in github

Can you clarify how can I run test cases in **parallel on multiple browsers** to perform "**compatibility testing**" ?  ( here I want to verify that a website works properly on all the major browsers ) ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vikram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distribution of tests is the only thing that is done by the Selenium Grid.

Parallel execution of tests is the attribute of a test runner. So for e.g., if you are making use of Java and working with `TestNG` as the test runner, then it would be `TestNG` that does the parallel execution of your tests.

In terms of **compatibility testing** you just need to ensure that the following criteria are met :

1. The Grid has all the required browser flavors as nodes (This is on the infrastructure side)
2. You either parameterize your tests such that the browser flavor is injectable from outside via a JVM argument etc., or you create multiple suite files

Since TestNG is a known to me, I am conveniently taking TestNG+Java as the example for the technology stack.

Comment: Thanks for answer to clarify; when you say use Grid for compatibility testing ( parallel execution ) with TestNG, did you mean create duplicate suite files which will be run on each of the nodes ( having unique browser ) ?

Comment: Yes either that, or if you leverage something like implementing a `IAlterSuiteListener` (which lets you alter contents of a suite through a listener), you can create multiple `<test>` tags wherein each tag can be constructed to have a different browser name but for the same set of tests. Its totally upto you to decide how you want to build it.

Comment: @vikramvi - If my response answered your question, please help accept it, so that the question gets closed.